# modal is not working without data-toggle and data-target attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using bootstrap 4 js and I have the link below to open a modal:

```
<a id="show_login_modal" href="">Login</a>
```

And then the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
...
</div>
```

But I want to open the modal with default jquery so I have the code below:

```
 $('#show_login_modal').click(function(){
    $('#login_modal').modal('show');
})

$('#close_login_modal').click(function(){
    $('#login_modal').modal('hide');
})
```

The issue is that like this when the login link is clicked it appears like a fade and then the fade disappears but the modal dont opens. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you show us the actual CSS/JS you're including for Bootstrap/Jquery/Popper? What does the rest of your Modal HTML look like?

Comment: Im using the default bootstrap 4 js and "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js". The css is also the bootstrap 4 default. With the data-toggle and data-target attribites and without the jquery to open and close modal it works, but with custom jquery dont.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce your issue using the code you've supplied https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/auLc73kj/. That's why we always encourage users to share a **minimal, concrete and verifiable example**, so that we can see how you've actually implemented it, and that the bug you've described can be reproduced reliably in your question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check if you have not included jquery twice. this probably happens due to that also.Also in some cases plugins create issues as well.

Make sure to put libraries in required order to get the result:

1- First bootstrap.min.css 2- jquery.min.js 3- bootstrap.min.js

(In other words, jquery.min.js must be called before bootstrap.min.js)

After ensuring the above kindly try the below snippet.

```
   <a id="show_login_modal" href="javascript:void(0)">Login</a>
```

then write your jquery code.
what is happening is that the empty href is not allowing the popup to open up, just do javascript:void(0) followed by your code.

Comment: can you create a codepen or plunkr to simulate the scenario?

Comment: try this:<a id="show_login_modal" href="javascript:void(0)">Login</a>

Comment: Thanks, it works with that "href="javascript:void(0)".

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can reproduce your results is by leaving the `href` attribute present and set to `href=""`.  Removing it or setting a hash value (`href="#"`) bypasses the problem and would be my recommended solution.

That, or transforming that element to a `<button>` to bypass hyperlink default behavior entirely.

```js
$('#button_modal, #link_modal').click(function(){
  $('#login_modal').modal('show')
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="button_modal">Login</button> or <a id="link_modal">Login</a>

<div id="login_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>My modal content here…</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would also note that while you're activating your Modal via JavaScript, it's not necessary to rely on JavaScript to also CLOSE your modal.  The `data-dismiss` attribute baked into the Modal structure will function regardless of how the modal was initialized.